# How to query multiple datasources & multiple templates in sitecore query

Tags: sitecore-query, tree-list

The content tree is as follows:

```
sitecore
|_content
  |_Site1
    |_Home
      |_Articles
        |_Category
          |_article1
          |_article2
  |_Site2
    |_Home
      |_Rewards
        |_September
          |_Reward1
          |_Reward2
```

There is a multilist field and I would like the user to be able to select only `Articles` and/or `Rewards`.
Before setting the source query I was trying it in the XPath Builder:

```
/sitecore/content/site1/home/articles/*/*|/sitecore/content/site2/home/rewards/*/*[@@templateid='{02DB4F77-20CB-463D-BF3A-177C6B6E2DA5}' or @@templateid='{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}']
```

The first guid is the article template & the 2nd is the reward template. The result only shows articles.

```
article1
article2
```

How should this query be to show both articles & rewards.

Any suggestions for Treelist are also welcome.

Comment: Instead of a single `|`, can you add 1 more like: `||`

Answer (score 3):

For multiple datasource location, for a Multi-list field, you should use 2 `||`. So, your query will be as follows:

```
sitecore/content/site1/home/articles/*/*||/sitecore/content/site2/home/rewards/*/*[@@templateid='{02DB4F77-20CB-463D-BF3A-177C6B6E2DA5}' or @@templateid='{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}']
```